# AES algorithm input and output restrictions

Tags: aes

I want to use AES encryption in my application. I have come across some open source implementations of aes algorithm. By looking at them, I am confused about the following parameters:

1. AES key length. It is mentioned that key length should be 128, 192 or 256 bytes. What if my key is simply five digits i.e. 23467
2. AES plain-text length : is there any restriction on the aes plain-text length ?
3. AES output: What would be the minimum size of aes output string if my key length is say 5 digits and plain-text is say 10 characters.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> AES key length. It is mentioned that key length should be 128, 192 or 256 bits. What if my key is simply five digits i.e. 23467

It seems you're thinking of the key as a password of sorts. It isn't. A cryptographic key isn't meant to be memorized. It is a long string of randomly generated bytes that should be stored somewhere safe.

You can derivate a cryptographic key from a password, though, for instance using a hash function. In that case you input `234567` and use the resulting digest as the key. This has some security implications, however, as it makes your key vulnerable to dictionary and rainbow table attacks. Look up "password based encryption" for details on how to approach this securely; in particular, have a look at [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2), described in [RFC2898](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898).

> AES plain-text length : is there any restriction on the aes plain-text length ?

AES is the block cipher, the underlying building block of an encryption system. By itself it can only encrypt a single block of data (16 bytes), so cryptographers have created several "modes of operation" that enable us to encrypt a plaintext of arbitrary length. [CTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29) is a fine example of a mode of operation that does not require any padding and can be parallelized.

> AES output: What would be the minimum size of aes output string if my key length is say 5 digits and plain-text is say 10 characters.

That's entirely dependent on the mode of operation. In your case it will probably be either 10 (when no padding is required, for example with [CTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29)) or 16 (for block-based modes such as [CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29)).

Comment: Thanks Pedro for the detailed explanation!! So does it mean that it is better to use a key that is derived from the pbkdf2 algorithm as the cipher key ? I am using c++ for the implementation. If possible, can you point me to AES implementation in CTR mode ?

Comment: @cppdev: Well, if you really want to use a password, than it is better to use PBKDF2. If you don't need a password, you can just randomly generate a key and use it (though storing it securely is a complicated matter). Regarding crypto libraries, I suggest Crypto++.

Comment: In all the implementations I've seen, the minimum output size for a block cipher will be the block size.  If a file isn't a multiple of the block size, but is at least one block in size, it's possible to have the last block overlap the previous one, thus avoiding any need for padding.  If, however, the file is shorter than a block, I know of no alternative to padding the thing to a block.

Comment: @supercat: Google "CTR mode of operation". It is essentially a way of making a block cipher act as a stream cipher.

Comment: @Pedro: CTR mode requires that no session key be used more than once.  Effectively, it requires a side channel large enough to deliver a session key.  The side channel need not be totally secure, but it must deliver something different every time some communications need to be encrypted, but must deliver the same thing to the entity that's decrypting the message as was delivered to the entity encrypting it.  To be sure, in the absence of a side channel, an adversary would be able to identify identical messages as identical, which could pose a security risk for short messages...

Comment: @Pedro: ...since an adversary who could determine the true value of one such message would determine it for all.  This would be a particular concern if the meaning of the answers depended upon context which wasn't present in the answers themselves (e.g. if an enemy gets the text "Omaha", but doesn't know the question, the enemy wouldn't be able to do anything with the info, but if the enemy intercepts questions "The Wild Kingdom show is sponsored by Mutual of __", and "We're attacking which beach?" and observes the same answer for both, the surprise attack would be greatly compromised.

Comment: @supercat: You are correct about the need for a "session key" (which I usually call nonce) to be transmitted alongside the message. But you underestimate the peril of reusing the nonce, or of not using it at all. CTR mode means encrypting the nonce + a 0-based counter several times, and XORing the result with the plaintext. In the absence of a nonce, the result of the encryption will be known by an attacker (since the counter always starts at zero). He need only XOR the ciphertext with it to obtain the original message again. This is exactly the same as reusing a stream cipher key.

Comment: @Pedro: I think we're in agreement; CTR mode has the advantage of not having a minimum message length, but requires a means of exchanging a nonce and ensuring that it will never be reused.  Other schemes don't require a nonce, but cannot encrypt messages shorter than the block length without padding.  Encrypting short messages without a nonce is sometimes dodgy, but there are times it is useful and appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

1. I think you mean 128 and 256. (Not 198.)
2. That's not a key. That's a password. You use an algorithm like PBKDF1 (google it) to derive a key from a password.
3. No. AES is a block cipher. It works on input blocks that are the same size as the key. You can use as many blocks as you like, chopping up your input into (say) 128-bit blocks. Make sure you use CBC or a similar mode for AES.
4. Your key is 128 or 256 bits. Your input would be 80 bits (10*8), padded to 128 or 256. Your output length is the same as the key size.

Try to find a crypto library that does most of the work for you. You don't want to mess around with just a basic AES function. You also need to handle IVs, AES modes, possibly a MAC, etc. I can't recommend anything because you don't say what language you're trying to use.

Comment: No, the output length is completely independent of the key size. It's either a) a multiple of the block size b) equal to the plaintext length.

Comment: Block size depends on the key size. So how can the output length be independent from it?

Comment: I have been somewhat sloppy in explaining 3, I'll give you that. (The reputation cap is a big disincentivizer...)

Comment: The size of an AES block is always 128 bits.